# I Made Tow function in pymongo but the out but that i want is different from i get from the function any ideas how can i fix it?

Tags: python, python-3.x, mongodb, pymongo

Funtion that save Close,Symbol, Timeframe

```
    def Save_(self,collection,symbol,price,TF):
    db = self.get_db('MTF')[collection]
    B = {'ts':time.time(),"Symbol":symbol,
                    "Price":price,'TimeFrame':TF}
    data = db.insert_one(B)
    return data
```

Function to get data from mongodb

```
def find_all(self,collection):
    db = self.get_db('MTF')[collection]
    Symbols ={}
    data = db.find({})
    for i in data:
        Symbols[i['Symbol']] = [i['Price'],i['TimeFrame']]
    return Symbols
```

images from mongodb
[2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/RLtnz.png

images from B Function
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/AtwSy.png

if u see the image from Function B only gave me on timeframe but Function Save have 4 timeframe

Comment: Please don't post images of code/data/errors/stacktraces/backtraces/etc.  Just format them and put them in code blocks with the question editor.

Comment: using complete sentences to describe the problem might engage more users in providing an answer. I hope it helps!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking at this loop:

```
for i in data:
    Symbols[i['Symbol']] = [i['Price'],i['TimeFrame']]
```

If you have the same `Symbol` coming from MongoDB, it will overwrite any previous value, so you will only get the final value for each Symbol which is what you are seeing.

To fix it you have a few options: you could check the key and either create or append the values to Symbols; or you could use `$push` in an aggregate query.

Comment: I really appreciate it.